# Set Apache Storm and Flink log level to display debug messages

Tags: java, logging, apache-flink, apache-storm

So I'm building a JAR with Storm and Flink applications where I log messages as the following:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

// ...

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Some.class);

// ...

LOG.debug("...");
LOG.info("...");
LOG.error("...");
```

Then I pass the JAR to `.../bin/storm` and `.../bin/flink` scripts and everything works, but the log level is set to `INFO`, I'd like to also display `DEBUG` messages **from my package only**.

I tried several things but I feel I'm just trying random things from the internet as I can't find an authoritative reference about how to obtain this and I'm having hard time wrapping my head around the incredibly confusing state of the log facilities for Java...

I'm asking about both Storm and Flink as I suspect that the root of my problem is the same but I might be wrong. Also I apologize if I don't provide a minimal example but there's really nothing to provide here.

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario:

> Then I pass the JAR to `.../bin/storm` and `.../bin/flink` scripts and everything works, but the log level is set to `INFO`, I'd like to also display `DEBUG` messages **from my package only**.

I ended up with the following suboptimal solution.

### Storm

For unknown reasons changing the `/path/to/storm/log4j2/worker.xml` file has no effect so I need to act programmatically:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

// ...

Configurator.setLevel("my.package", Level.ALL);
```

### Flink

It's enough to add a line to `/path/to/flink/conf/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.my.package=ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

For Storm, your log configuration is in `storm/log4j2/worker.xml`. It's a log4j2 configuration file, so you can find out what options there are by looking at the log4j2 documentation here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html.

I'm not as familiar with Flink, but I'd suspect it's similar. [Here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html#configuring-logback) is Flink's page on it, which mentions that you should have a `logback.xml` file in your `conf` directory.

Comment: Changing the level from `worker.xml` yields no effect in Storm, even changing the pattern does nothing. While in Flink the relevant file is `log4j.properties`. Anyway, I was expecting something to be placed in my JAR so to not touch *system* files.

Comment: Please see this answer as a supplement to the above https://stackoverflow.com/a/58456284/8845188

Comment: If changing worker.xml has no effect, your cluster may have non-default settings in your conf/storm.yaml pointing to other directories, or you may have set the topology property described in my answer.

Comment: My Storm directory is basically untouched from the tar.gz. I suspect that changing `storm/log4j2/worker.xml` doesn't apply to `bin/storm local some.jar ...`.

Comment: Ah, yes right. When you run in local mode, the log configuration will just depend on the log4j2.xml you package in your jar. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the log level and which classes log on a Flink cluster, please adapt

- `FLINK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties` if you are using `log4j`
- `FLINK_HOME/conf/logback.xml` if you are using `logback`

before you start the Flink cluster.

These files will be read when you deploy the Flink cluster. Note that these settings cannot be changed at runtime, unless you are replacing Flink's `log4j` logger with `log4j2` which supports to load settings dynamically.

Comment: Yes for Flink is enough to alter `log4j.properties` but the Storm counterpart seems to have no effect.